# IE/Edge not applying transform: translate to table row

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transforms, microsoft-edge

When adding a CSS transformation like `transform:translate(0px, -45px)` to a table row, Internet Explorer (tested 10 and 11) and Microsoft Edge do not correctly display the transformation.

Using some simple code as an example:

```html
<table style="width:500px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="height: 30px; background-color:red; color:white;">
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 30px; background-color:blue; color:white;">
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 30px; background-color:yellow; color:black; transform:translate(0, -45px);">
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbePU.png) shows the problem: row 3 should be positioned on top of rows 1 and 2, but in IE/Edge, it hasn't moved. Almost any other modern browser behaves as expected. [Microsoft](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/transforms?filter=f3f0000bf&search=transform) notes that IE 10+ and Edge should support (unprefixed) transform, and based on the standard, elements with display table-row are supported.

Does anyone have any clue why this doesn't work?

Comment: Very nice work around https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [defined in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element), *transformable-elements* includes elements whose `display` property computes to *table-row*. As such, you are correct to expect *transform* to relocate table rows on the screen. Microsoft Edge appears to lack this support.

Edge *does*, however, translate *table cells*. This may provide temporary relief for the time being. I am going to [work up a few tests](https://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/9tog66gn/) to ensure that we are accurately implementing this functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately, translating the cells will not work for me, since I need to really move the row for my implementation of a drag and drop interface to work (when checking overlap on possible dropzones). Also, translating cells when the table row has a background color set looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I am facing the same issue. You can make the tr display:block but... this will destroy your table. Let's hope microsoft will deal with this fast.