# Knockout beforeRemove and CSS animations not working together in IE

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, css-animations

I have a table that uses a Knockout foreach to populate some rows. To cut a long story short the viewmodel gets updated with new data periodically and any rows that are no longer valid get removed from this table.

Using the beforeRemove binding a CSS animation is then applied to fade the row out. This works fine on Chrome and Firefox but for some reason will not work in IE11. The exactly same code for the animation will work in IE 11 if used outside of the beforeRemove. I've put together a simplified version of my code in the snippet below.

Any ideas on why IE is having problems with this? Thanks!

```js
var item = function(name) {
  this.name = ko.observable(name);
}

$('document').ready(function () {
  function queueViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.queueItems = ko.observableArray([
      new item("one"),
      new item("two"),
      new item("three"),
      new item("four")
    ]);
    self.removeItem = function(item) {
      self.queueItems.remove(item)
    }
    self.beforeRemoveFadeOut = function (element) {
        $(element).addClass('animated fadeOutUp')
        .one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function () {
            //Actual code removes an element here
            $(element).remove();
        });
    }
  }
  var queueViewModel = new queueViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(queueViewModel,document.getElementById('wrapper'));
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Remove Item</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="template: { foreach: queueItems, beforeRemove: beforeRemoveFadeOut }">
      <tr>
        <td><span data-bind="text:name"></span></td>
        <td><a href='#' data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem">Remove</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a known [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718443/ie-edge-not-applying-transform-translate-to-table-row) with IE11 when you transform table row elements... When I try to translate a table row in IE11, it doesn't show anything at all:

[image]

```css
table {
  background: red;
}

tr {
  transform: translate3d(50px, 0, 0);
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>test</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Somehow, this results in the complete animation not being loaded. That, in turn, results in the `animationEnd` event never triggering.

I'd suggest you either:

1. Use other HTML elements (`<li>`, `<div>`, etc.) in your markup, or
2. Use a transition that does not use a `transform` internally. You can look these up in the animate library's source.

I couldn't find much about the table-row transform "bug"... But I tested both of these alternatives and they do fix your problem.

```js
var item = function(name) {
  this.name = ko.observable(name);
}

$('document').ready(function () {
  function queueViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.queueItems = ko.observableArray([
      new item("one"),
      new item("two"),
      new item("three"),
      new item("four")
    ]);
    self.removeItem = function(item) {
      self.queueItems.remove(item)
    }
    self.beforeRemoveFadeOut = function (element) {
        $(element)
          .one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function () {
            $(element).remove();
          })
          .addClass('animated fadeOutUp');
    }
  }
  var queueViewModel = new queueViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(queueViewModel,document.getElementById('wrapper'));
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  
    <ul data-bind="template: { foreach: queueItems, beforeRemove: beforeRemoveFadeOut }">
      <li class="">
        <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
        <a href='#' data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem">Remove</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, you've hit the nail on the head! Unfortunately moving to another HTML element won't work for me due to the effort involved and the fact that I really need a table. I have changed to an animation that doesn't use a transform and that has confirmed that you are correct. I will potentially look at applying this animation just for IE 11 and keep my favoured animation for other browsers.